# How to encrypt files under linux for cloud storage

Tags: linux, encryption, cloud-storage

How to encrypt files under linux for cloud storage

I am searching for a file based encryption tool, which I can use in Linux (Mint) to store files in google drive.

I really like encfs. But since die security audit (https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm) it comes to my understanding, that it is not recommended for any cloud storage solution. It's fine with encryption “at home”, but in the “cloud” an attacker could get multiple versions of your files and..... well do stuff... I have no deep knowledge of encryption. I am just trying to understand the risks.

**My requirements:**

- Incremental backups/Syncs => no container based encryption
- I am using linux. Just need something for encryption. No android app or anything fancy.
- encfs is no longer an option

I do not know how secure ecryptfs is. Are there any other apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use openssl for encrypt a file:

- Encryption

  openssl aes-256-cbc -in yourfile.txt -out file.enc
- Decryption

  openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in file.enc -out yourfile.txt

If you want to encrypt many files, you can create a 7z archive with password (it uses a 256bit AES encryption)

Comment: Modern OpenSSL-versions emit following warning: "*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better." Obvious fix is to use `-pbkdf2` to derive a better encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

**Truecrypt is still one of the best solutions I think. Why? Ease of use!**

You have a local disk where you put all your files in. They are automatically encrypted. When something changes, only the changed block of the image is synced, so when you change something on that truecrypt volume, you don't need to upload the entire file.

Is it safe? I guess it is. Maybe the NSA has a way (and the means) to crack your file open, but for the average hacker I don't see how they can do this.

Answer (score 0):

## EncFS

One solution is using **EncFS** which is similar to *Ecryptfs* and is based on the filesystem FUSE.
 It has been ported to all major systems (except iOS): [Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS), [Windows](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html), [OS X](http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2013/07/01/encrypt-your-dropbox-with-encfs-on-mac-os-x/), and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite&hl=en).
You will find a great tutorial at [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/121737/how-to-encrypt-cloud-storage-on-linux-and-windows-with-encfs/).

EncFS encrypts each file and stores the metadata in an xml file in the same folder. That one you can mount in the system and access the files easily. It is very useful for cloud services.

Downsides:

- An [audit](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm) from Jan. 2014 revealed that under very specific circumstances it could be possible to break encryption.
- Installation is not always very straight forward, but at least it's possible.
- Plus the tool hasn't been under active development for a long time but the dev [vgough](https://github.com/vgough/encfs) just [announced](https://vgough.github.io/encfs/) he would start developing again if there is interest.